# Definition of $S_1(A,B)$

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

The definition of first selection principle is well known: $S_1(A,B)$.
 Let $A$ and $B$ be families of sets. The symbol $S_1(A, B)$ denotes the statement:
for each sequence $(A_n : n \in \omega)$ of elements of $A$ there is a sequence
$(x_n : n\in \omega)$ such that each $x_n$ is an element of $A_n$, and $\{x_n : n\in \omega\}$ is an element of $B$.

Can we assume that $x_{n_k}=\emptyset$ for $k\in \omega$ ?

Comment: You say $x_n$ is an element of $A_n$.  I would think that in most cases $\emptyset$ is not an element of $A_n$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it is so. It is interesting that in the definition $S_{fin}(A,B)$ we can choose empty subsets $X_n\subset A_n$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are families of subsets of a set $S$ and $B$ is "closed upward", then I think $S_1(A,B)$ is equivalent to the following: for each sequence $(A_n:n\in\omega)$ of elements of $A$ there is a sequence $(B_n:n\in\omega)$ such that $B_n\subset A_n$, $|B_n|\leq 1$ and $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}B_n\in B$.

Comment: Yes, in this interpretation we get that the answer is positive.... Since $ B_{n_k}$ can be empty ....

Comment: If I understood @GeraldEdgar's point properly, he was pointing out that you were asking whether you could take the *elements* $x_n$ to be empty, which seems "ill typed" (a priori they *are* just elements, not sets).  Also, you have only defined $x_n$ in your statement; what is $x_{n_k}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question to mean "must we chose an element $x_n$ for all $n$?". (This is in accordance with the comments.)

**Answer.** Officially, the answer is "Yes", you must chose an element for each $n$. However, as pointed out in the comments, often you can prove this makes no difference if you are allowed to *not* chose elements. This is true for all classic selective covering properties of type $S_1(A,B)$.

For some properties this is not entirely trivial, but still provable. For example, $S_1(\Gamma,\Gamma)=S_{\le 1}(\Gamma,\Gamma)$ because WLOG the covers get finer with $n$. If you think about it, this is the essence of the now-classic proof that $S_1(\Gamma,\Gamma)=S_\text{fin}(\Gamma,\Gamma)$.

Comment: Thanks!  I was more interested  the principle $S_1(\Omega, \Gamma)$, but i find Gerlits-Nagy's result  that  $S_1(\Omega, \Gamma)={ \Omega\choose \Gamma}$.

Comment: If I understood correctly, then this is true for any principle in The Scheepers Diagram ( Including the Borel covers ) ?

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov Yes, the proof for $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$ is the same. Indeed, in courses I prove for $S_1(\Gamma,\Gamma)$ and then deduce for $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$ as an immediate consequence.

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov Yes, this holds for all of the Scheepers diagram, and also in the Borel case. Same proofs work.